# Comparing database values with values from a GridView

Tags: c#

I have a block of C# code here that stores data to an `ArrayList` from the database and compares each with the values from the `GridView`.

Is there a way to reduce the line of code and improve its readability?

```
 while (DataReader.Read())
{
    arrHostName.Add(DataReader.GetString(0));
    arrUsers.Add(DataReader.GetString(2));
    arrPSName.Add(DataReader.GetString(3));
}           
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
{
    string rowHostName = row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString();
    string rowUsers = row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString();
    string rowPSName= row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString();

    foreach (string a in arrHostName)
    {
        if (rowHostName == a.ToString())
        { 
            row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        }
    }
    foreach (string a in arrUsers)
    {
        if (rowUsers == a.ToString())
        {
            row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        }
    }
    foreach (string a in arrPSName)
    {
        if (rowPSName == a.ToString())
        {
            row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like what you want is [`ArrayList.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains.aspx).

```
string rowHostName = row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString();
string rowUsers = row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString();
string rowPSName= row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString();

if (arrHostName.Contains(rowHostName) 
    || arrUsers.Contains(rowUsers) 
    || arrPSName.Contains(rowPSName))
{ 
    row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
}
```

And if you only use the collections above to check if they contain some values, you should prefer [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) over `ArrayList`.

Of course, you should then change the names of the local variables accordingly, from `arrHostName` to `hostNames` and so on. It is always better not to clutter variable names with type information in C#, whose type system is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

for improvement, to reduce no of iterations

```
    foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
    {
        string rowHostName = row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString();
        string rowUsers = row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString();
        string rowPSName= row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString();

        foreach (string a in arrHostName)
        {
            if (rowHostName == a)
            { 
                row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
 goto Outer;
            }
        }
        foreach (string a in arrUsers)
        {
            if (rowUsers == a)
            {
                row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
 goto Outer;
            }
        }
        foreach (string a in arrPSName)
        {
            if (rowPSName == a)
            {
                row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
 goto Outer;
            }
        }
 Outer:
                continue;
    }
```

And if all `arraylist` having same `length`, then you could reduce no of `for loops`

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
        {
            string rowHostName = row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString();
            string rowUsers = row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString();
            string rowPSName= row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString();

           for (int i = 0; i < arrHostName.Length; i++)
            {
               if (arrHostName[i].ToString() == rowHostName || arrUsers[i].ToString() == rowUsers || arrPSName[i].ToString() == rowPSName)
                {
                    row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

**Edited**

```
if (arrHostName[i] == rowHostName || arrUsers[i] == rowUsers || arrPSName[i] == rowPSName)
```

**Updated**

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
            {
                string rowHostName = row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString();
                string rowUsers = row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString();
                string rowPSName= row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString();

                if(arrHostName.Contains(rowHostName) || arrUsers.Contains(rowUsers) || arrPSName.Contains(rowPSName))
                   {
                        row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
                    }


            }
```

**Further improvement -- reduced more no of lines**

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
                {
                    if(arrHostName.Contains(row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString()) || arrUsers.Contains(row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString()) || arrPSName.Contains(row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString()))
                       {
                            row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
                       }
                }
```

Comment: the reason why I have added `goto Outer;` is- if you changes the back color of a row in first `for`, then there is no need to go to other `for`

Comment: But is there another way to reduce the 3 foreach?

Comment: @QKWS length of arraylist are not same right? I mean all having same length or ?

Comment: @QKWS arraylist length would be same as the no of rows coming from datareader right?

Comment: yes.. they will be the same.

Comment: @QKWS edited `if` logic, so It would work

Comment: I got an error of Error: ArrayList does not contain a definition for 'Length'

Comment: use `Count` instead of `length`

Comment: For some reason, your code is not working for me. Rows doesn't change into Yellow Background.

Comment: Check the values in `if` statement

Comment: `if (arrHostName[i].ToString() == rowHostName || arrUsers[i].ToString() == rowUsers || arrPSName[i].ToString() == rowPSName)`

Comment: Does this code solve your prob

Comment: I suggest you make your edits more *seamless* - readers can use the edit history to see all the revisions; posts are easier to read if they *look* like they were written in one shot ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would be best way to do this.

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow row in Grid2.Rows)
                {
                    if(arrHostName.Contains(row.Cells["HostName"].Value.ToString()) || arrUsers.Contains(row.Cells["Users"].Value.ToString()) || arrPSName.Contains(row.Cells["PS_NAME"].Value.ToString()))
                       {
                            row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            row.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
                       }
                }
```